# Creating file on the fly in php (Issue with extension)

Tags: php

I'm creating a file on the fly in PHP containing plain text and then telling the browser to download it using the following code:

```
# Create the verification file and force-download it.
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.ecf'"); #1
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo "...";
```

As shown in the line designated with **`#1`**, I want the to-be-downloaded file to be named **`.ecf`**, but with my current code, when it is downloaded it's named **`ecf`** *(without extension)*.

How can I tell PHP to save the file as **`.ecf`** instead of **`ecf`**?

---

**Note:** The issue I'm facing lies in the downloaded file not having an extension and not in trying to create and download a file on the fly, so please refrain from marking this question as a duplicate of the myriad existent questions regarding that.

---

**Edit:** As also pointed out in the comments, I tried escaping the dot, but then the downloaded file is named **`-.ecf`**.

Comment: Presumably you've had no issues with names that were not "extension only", such as "file.ecf".  Have you tried escaping the dot (`\.ecf`), or any other methods than the one you've indicated in the question?

Comment: Yes @cale_b, I tried escaping the dot, but unfortunately the file is then named **`-.ecf`**

Comment: I suspect it's refusing to default to a dotfile, as getting someone to download a file like `.profile` or `.htaccess` could cause mayhem if saved to the right spot.

Comment: are you on a Windows server?

Comment: @RST yes, I'm using Windows.

Comment: @cale_b - why would OP not include a filename with extension?

Comment: It seems you can fool the system by using '.ecf.' (not tested). It's not a PHP issue, it is Windows.

Comment: Hey @RST, I tried it just now, but the downloaded file is now named **`ecf-`** with, again, no extension.

Comment: Bummer. That seems to work on a regular Windows PC (I have tested it now). I assumed it would work on a Windows server as well.

Comment: Do you tested this with your browser? or with script.
Maybe browser have security block to not download files started with dot - typical for others OS than Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security restriction at the browser level. Files starting with a `.` - "dotfiles" - have special function on OSX and Linux (and are hidden by default), so allowing you to drop one in the user's Downloads folder could potentially allow malicious acts.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#downloading-resources

> Otherwise, *if named type is known to be potentially dangerous* (e.g. it will be treated by the platform conventions as a native executable, shell script, HTML application, or executable-macro-capable document) then optionally alter filename to add a known-safe extension (e.g. ".txt").

Comment: Thanks for the information @ceejayoz. Quite some time has passed since the posting of the question and I've figured it out eventually, but I'm confident people with a similar issue will greatly benefit from your answer!

Comment: @AngelPolitis Thanks! Not sure why, but this popped up to the front page today. :-)

Comment: You're welcome! I think it popped up, because of the other answer. Not sure how the other guy dug it up though 

Answer (score -1):

You can create a file with php. Here is a try that I did with .php extension and it worked:

```
<?
$file = "test.php";
$content ="testing\n That is\n working";
if(!is_file($file)){
  file_put_contents($file, $content);
}
?>
```

The ! before is_file means that it checks if the file doesn't exit with the name then create it and fill it with the content from $content.

Maybe this is something for you. Just point the header to $file?

Comment: Hey @Cordux, what do you aim to answer with your post? It doesn't seem related to the topic.